# Application gets crashed after user taps on button multiple times

Tags: android

Application gets crashed after user taps on button multiple times

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at fragment.FragmentHealthBelief.onSuccess(FragmentHealthBelief.java:117)
            at datamodel.JsonParser$1.onResponse(JsonParser.java:97)
            at datamodel.JsonParser$1.onResponse(JsonParser.java:92)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```